# in mongodb and angular based website do not function authentication part

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I want to compare username and password that user entered with stored username & password. I used MongoDB as my database. used angular as front end and node as the back end. 
I used this code for authentication part and it does not occur any error. but when entering username and password by using "postman chrome" it says"could not get any response.
value storing part is ok and there are some data inside the database.

this is code part related to authentication.

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next)=>{
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;

 User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'user not found'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secreat, {
                expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
            });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                token: 'JWT'+token,
                user:{
                    id: user._id,
                    name:user.name,
                    username: user.username,
                    email:user.email
                }
            });
        } else{
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong passport'}); 
        }
      });
  });
});
```

this is the screenshot of postman chrome response.

[image]

Comment: `if(err) throw err;` could be the culprit. Instead of throwing an error you should return one in the response like you have for `if(!user)`. Since you aren't catching the error anywhere, a response is never being sent

Comment: Thank you for your comment. it was useful for me.